# How to display a loading message until the content is fully loaded

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am using "http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_ajax_database.asp" for displaying data from database on onchange of dropdown list. I have a huge amount of data in database. So it's taking time to load. Hence I would like to display a loading message somewhere in the page until the data display.

Code:

```
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

 <form>
 <select name="users" onChange="showUser(this.value)" style="margin-left: -680px;margin-top: -10px;">
 <option value="1">Current Projects</option>
 <option value="2">All Projects</option>
 </select>
 </form>
 </div></div>
 <div id="txtHint"> /*Content*/ </div>
```

getuser.php:
   Database queries to display data.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is easier to juse a javascribt library/framework like JQuery for Ajax requests or plain everything javascript. If you want to do it the old school way, that this should be able to help you out:

```
if(obj.readyState == 0)
{
 document.getElementById('copy').innerHTML = "Sending Request...";
}
if(obj.readyState == 1)
{
 document.getElementById('copy').innerHTML = "Loading Response...";
}
if(obj.readyState == 2)
{
 document.getElementById('copy').innerHTML = "Response Loaded...";
}
if(obj.readyState == 3)
{
 document.getElementById('copy').innerHTML = "Response Ready...";
}
if(obj.readyState == 4)
{
 if(obj.status == 200)
 {
  return true;
 }
 else if(obj.status == 404)
 {
  // Add a custom message or redirect the user to another page
  document.getElementById('copy').innerHTML = "File not found";
 }
 else
 {
  document.getElementById('copy').innerHTML = "There was a problem retrieving the XML.";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It's pretty easy actually**, just put the message / image you want in the div, like that :

```
<div id="txtHint"> Loading... </div>
```

And when the data is loaded and JS :

```
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

**This will empty the div and replace with the Ajax content.**

*Actually, I think your code is already working.*